# Subprocess error while installing sentence-transformers

Tags: python, large-language-model, sentence-transformers

error: subprocess-exited-with-error:

```
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]

      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Latest version of Python
I am trying to install this in my Python virtual environment.

I even installed rust to see if it works, but it is showing the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

1. download installer for rustup on https://rustup.rs/
2. install rustup
3. `rustup --version`
4. `pip install sentence-transformers` again